# Favorite Windows keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a keyboard junkie.  I love having a key sequence to do everything.  What are your favorite keyboard shortcuts?

I'll start by naming a couple of mine:

1 - <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to access the windows menu for the current window

2 - <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename a file in Windows Explorer

Comment: Amazing how many closer-to-being-related-to-programming questions have been closed but this one managed to survive...

Comment: <Tab>*23 <Space> for "vote to close".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> .. <kbd>9</kbd>** -- Start quick launch shortcut at that index (Windows Vista).

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>** -- Crash your computer: *[Windows feature lets you generate a memory dump file by using the keyboard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244139)*

@gabr -- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is *show desktop*, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> minimizes all windows. Hitting <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> twice brings everything back as it has only shown the desktop window in front of the other windows.

Comment: I picked yours as the "answer" b/c I have never heard of the ctrl-scroll lock, scroll lock one before.

Comment: Wow, what the devil.. I've never heard about this one

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I keep trying the scroll lock combination and NOTHING happens.

Comment: You have to enable it via the registry. Follow the link from the answer.

Comment: Of course Win+D twice does NOT actually restore the window order correctly, oh no, that would have been too nice of MS. If you have 15 windows spread on three screens chances are that you will get a completely different set of foreground windows after doing it twice.

Comment: In Windows7 Win+1..9 is for programs pinned to task bar (in case you wanted to try it on restored QuickLanuch toolbar).

Comment: `Win` + `1` .. `9` are fantastic, and one would think that it would work also with the numeric pad, but it does not. Does any one if there's a way to make it work that way? I can't use the regular numbers at the top of the keyboard because my keyboard is set differently.

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> to bring up computer information and to access environment variables under the *Advanced* tab.

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to go straight to the run box (though I barely use this anymore since I started with [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/)).

Of course <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> but also <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for going backwards.

Oh, and personally, I hate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> for closing tabs - too much of a pinky stretch.

Oh and try <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on Windows 7 (with *[Aero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero)* on).

Comment: IMO, default shortcut of Launchy sucks because Alt-Space is too useful for me to let L to hi-jack it. So, I re-map Launchy to Win-Space. What is your preference?

Comment: alt space is fine by me, win-space woudl be harder to hit, but to each his own!

Comment: you can do anything alt-space provides with other hot keys, so it's okay for launchy to take over it. However, Launchy is found to consume too much resource for me, i just pin the most frequently used programs to my start menu. It's good.

Comment: Ctrl+W closes tabs or documents in all good apps.

Answer (score 15):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> to close a program.
- <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to lock my workstation
- <kbd>Ctr</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd> to copy text from a textbox
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to capture a shot of just a window
- <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the "Run" dialog (XP Pro only- does something else on XP Home)

Comment: Alt+PrintScreen is handy, especially on XPs. Vista comes with a handy accessory - Snipping Tool. At least the enterprise edition does.

Comment: Just `Ctrl+Ins` is copy. `Shift+Ins` is paste!

Comment: `Ctrl`-`Shift`-`Ins` OMG! That's absolutely great. Didn't know about that. I have used 3rd party SW for this purpose. From which Windows' version is it supported? Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 11):

- <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all applications
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open Task Manager

Comment: I always wanted to use Win-D more, but it's a one way action.  There doesn't seem to be a way to restore all the windows to the state they were at, unfortunately.

Comment: @Zigdon: Win-D is a toggle. Press it again and the windows should be restored. Are you confusing this with Win-M? (I use XP)

Comment: It is - Win-D. At least on XP.

Another way is to use Win-M to minimize, Win-Shift-M to undo.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to lock the computer..

Answer (score 8):

To maximize a window: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>
To restore a window: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>
To minimize a window: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>
To close a window: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: This is completely language-dependent. For instance, in Swedish Windows, you use Alt+Space, M to minimize.

Answer (score 7):

- <kbd>F4</kbd> in windows explorer to access the location bar trivially.
- <kbd>Menu</kbd> key (next to the right-hand windows key) + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to create a new folder in explorer.

Comment: ALT + E just accesses the location bar.

Comment: [Ctrl + Shift + N] creates a new folder in explorer

Answer (score 7):

I try to stick to my keyboard as well. I frequently use...

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to Lock my system
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close a program
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to launch from the Run Window (Used for frequent programs instead of going through QuickLaunch)
- <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename a file
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to go to Desktop
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to cycle through open programs

### Visual Studio

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> (debug), <kbd>P</kbd> (process), <kbd>W</kbd> (webdev process)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> (Tools), <kbd>P</kbd> (process), <kbd>W</kbd> (webdev process) for VS 2008
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> to collapse to definitions
- <kbd>F5</kbd> to launch
- <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, and <kbd>F11</kbd> for stepping through debugger
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to format a document
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> to comment
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment

### Browser

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close tab
- <kbd>F6</kbd> to focus on the address bar

Answer (score 7):

How is this not here?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>  to **`System Information`**.  Then the system **`PATH`** variable is only 2 clicks away ([Advanced system settings](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Whole-Wide-World/237126446329079?ref=hl),<kbd>Environment Variables...</kbd>)

Comment: You can also hit the win key and start typing Environment Variabl.. and it would lead there without any clicks :)

Comment: This was already specified by @George.

Answer (score 6):

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open an Windows Explorer reference
2. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> from the Run box
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the start menu

And, of course, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to close things.

Comment: Opening the start menu also works like a charm by clicking <kbd>Win</kbd> (on Windows 7 at least)

Answer (score 6):

A few basic keyboard shortcuts for clipboard operations, text selection, and navigation that work in most Windows programs:

**Clipboard**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> - Clipboard Cut
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Clipboard Copy
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - Clipboard Paste

**Selecting Text**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Select All (in the current field or document)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+[navigate with <kbd>▲</kbd>/<kbd>▼</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>, or <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>/<kbd>Pg Dn</kbd>] - Select text between the caret's previous and new positions.  Continue to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and navigate to select more text.

**Navigation**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> - Move the caret to the previous/next word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> - Go to beginning/end of the current field or document

**Bonus Tip!**

- Before submitting a web form where you've entered a lot of text into a text field (for example, an email in a web-based mail client -- or a new question or answer on Stack Overflow!), do a quick <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the field.  That way, if something goes wrong with the submit (even if the browser crashes), you haven't lost your work -- you have a copy of it sitting on the clipboard.

Comment: Also Ctrl + Shift + arrow keys lets you select words faster. 
Shift + End / Begin : select everything from carret to end / begin

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to go straight to the task manager without any intermediate dialogs.

Answer (score 4):

I use the free [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), then I define my own shortcuts:

- dobule tap <kbd>F4</kbd> quickly => Close active Windows (like Alt+F4 but with one finger only)
- double tap <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> quickly => [Find and Run Robot](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/findrun/index.html) task manager
- <kbd>F12</kbd> => open Find and Run Robot Locate32 plugin (I use it like a very lightweight desktop search)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> in a command window => scroll back / forward command line like the mouse wheel
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> in a command windows => close window

etc.

Answer (score 4):

In calc, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> cycle between Hex, Dec, Oct, Bin mode.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows Vista, if you bring up the Start menu and search for a program, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will run the selected program as Administrator. So to open an Administrator command prompt:

<kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type "cmd", <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For when you have a window stuck under an appbar and can't get at that window's system menu to move it:

<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>spacebar</kbd> -> <kbd>M</kbd> -> <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> -> <kbd>return</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

1. <kbd>[image]</kbd>+[type name of program] to launch a program in Vista
2. <kbd>[image]</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for explorer
3. <kbd>[image]</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for find
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to swap between programs
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to swawp between tabs

Not really a 'Windows' shortcut, but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>numpad</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+[arrows] to move and resize windows and move them to another monitor using [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) are absolutely great.  I would never use large or multiple monitors without them.

Comment: Just downloaded WinSplit - wowza that's useful!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to minimise all. Useful for quick trips to the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favourite is <kbd>WinKey</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> - shuts Windows down! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>/<kbd>Break</kbd> for System Properties
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: open windows explorer
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: find
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: run
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>: minimize all windows
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>: restore all windows
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>: close program
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: switch between tasks
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>: task manager

Answer (score 2):

1. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>** : *Run Task Manager*
2. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>** : *Copy/Paste*
3. **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>** : *Cut (text)*
4. **<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>** : *Lock System*
5. **<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>** : *Run*
6. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause Break</kbd>** : *Break Loop (Programming)*
7. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>** : *Tab Change*

Answer (score 1):

Repeat <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> Twice!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> -> Open Task Manager

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> -> closes windows in MDIs where Ctrl+F4 doesn't work

Those and the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> is Vista are used constantly.

Also a nice trick is <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> -> cycles through program groups on task bar in Windows Xp and Server 2003. (i.e. same as Vista without the previews).

Answer (score 1):

Many say that <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> minimises all applications. Not true. It simply shows the desktop. Use Win-M to minimise all open windows. Use Win-Shift-M to restore them to their previous state.

By the way, did you notice that the Sift key can be combined with most of the usual shortcuts? e.g. Alt+Tab : cycle through applications 1->2->3->4->...1 Add Shift to the shortcut and you will be cycling in the opposite direction 1<-2<-3<-4<- ...1

Control+Tab to switch between Tabs in most Windows applications (sadly not in Eclipse) - you can already guess what Ctr+Shift+Tab will do. Especially handy in Firefox, IE, etc... where you have more than one Tab open and try going to the previous one. Very handy.

And one more tip, this is **soooo handy**, I love it. Only found out about it a couple of weeks ago:

**FireFox** users: tired of `rightclick->Open Link in New Tab`?

Click a link with MIDDLE mouse button and it will open in a new tab (depends on your Tabs settings in Tools->Options but by default would work). The magical thing about this is that it works even for the browser's Back button! Also when you type a search term into the Google box (usually in top right corner) and middle-click the search button, the search results are opened in a new tab. Closing tabs is also much easier with the middle mouse button (of course you can do Ctrl+W but sometimes the mouse is simply in your hand). You don't have to click the tab's red button to close it. Simply middle-click anywhere on the tab and it will be closed.

**EDIT**
I just tried the middle button in IE 7 and seems to work just like it does in FF, except for the <kbd>Back</kbd>-button and Search widget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have favorites among keyboard shortcuts -- they are all utility entities to me...

Except for <kbd>[image]</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, which means another coffee break!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to show the desktop and then Win+D to bring all the windows back again.

Answer (score 0):

All those of you that mentioned <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> missed out the shift versions too

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> - move one tab back
<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> - move one window back in task switcher

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (Firefox)

Comment: Obviously, Win+1 will only start Firefox if Firefox is the first icon in the Windows taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

The most "important" shortcut is the [Secure Attention Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

On XP you usually have to [enable it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281980) otherwise it just runs Task Manager.

While logged in, SAS brings up the Windows Security dialog on its own [Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681928(VS.85).aspx), which will get you out of almost anything (such as a hung full-screen DirectX app).

The Task Manager shortcut is now (and always was) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

(this answer applies to NT4, 2000, XP and 2003. I can't speak for Vista)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (VS IDE)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a keyboard shortcut, but my favourite trick is to bind the large thumb button on the rat to move window, the smaller thumb button to resize. That way, windows can be moved and resized very easily and naturally. You can probably to that in windows too.

As for *keyboard* tricks, I use right ctrl+keypad to pick (one of nine) virtual screens. Very quick and natural.

Answer (score 0):

I mapped some global hotkeys:

- In Winamp I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (same as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> for me) to Pause. If someone wants my attention while I've got headphones on, far easier to press a couple of buttons than click the mouse on a button that's about five pixels wide.
- I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to run calc.

Comment: Astonishing how many people have a physical calculator on their desk because they can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

In any dialog with tabs, Ctrl-Page Up/Down to cycle between the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to setting up shortcut keys to program shortcuts in start menu (standard Windows feature). Once the program is started, pressing such shortcut brings the focus to the window instead of starting another copy.

For example, to pause Winamp I just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> (and I can have it working without tray or taskbar icons).

The only drawback is that some program names start with the same letter so I have to pick up other letters for them. =)

Comment: You can get two per letter, so, Ctrl+Alt+w is different than Ctrl+Alt+W.  Numbers work, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a hint for a good source to look from - if no one cited it above [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shortcuts) has all ( for the most important OS's) - not the best

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key in any Windows Explorer window (including the common dialog windows) to go up one level in the folder hierarchy.  This is a shortcut for a button next to the folder combo-box. Microsoft removed this functionality in Windows Vista and later in order to make Windows Explorer more like a web browser; now the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key operates as a "Back" button.  (If anyone knows of a way to go up one level in Vista and later, please comment!)

Comment: [Alt-D], "..", ENTER

Alt-D to give focus to the menu bar
.. to go up a level
ENTER to execute

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F5</kbd> to execute seems to be the one I use the most.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows**
Windows right click key, next to the right alt can be very useful.

For the noobs, 

<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to cycle through inputs

<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to cycle through the windows

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to cycle through the tabs

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>printscreen</kbd> to snapshot the entire screen

and <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>printscreen</kbd> to snapshot the current window

for some dialog windows <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> will copy the message

**Console**

<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd>,<kbd>p</kbd> to paste in windows console

<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd> to mark in console

<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to cycle autocomplete in console

**Visual Studio**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> Search in files
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> Search page
<kbd>F12</kbd> Goto definition of the current word
<kbd>F2</kbd> Rename selected text
<kbd>F4</kbd> Open properties tab for selected
Highlight section and <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> Indent a block of text

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd> Format Document

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>c</kbd> Comment out highlighted text

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>u</kbd>,<kbd>c</kbd> Un-comment highlighted text

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd> Collapse to definitions 

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>,<kbd>m</kbd> Toggle open and close the current method/function

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd> Open solution pane

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd> Open output pane
and
 of course <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> for intellisense

Answer (score 0):

My favourites are the following (which I have not been able to spot in the responses above):

- <kbd>F12</kbd> Save as in Office applications
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> Scroll to the top of the page in most applications or go to cell A1 in Excel
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> Go back to the cursor in a Word document or back to the active cell in Excel
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> Select a whole table in Excel from its top-left corner. If the table starts at A1, use in conjunction with the above for super speedy one-handed table selecting

It's already been said, but I'm repeating <kbd>F6</kbd> to go directly to the browser address bar because it rocks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> mentioned yet.  This one has saved my butt **many** times.  It's the *Undo* command, which is really useful if you've just deleted a paragraph of text, or accidentally pasted over the wrong segment of code you just wrote.

Others in that vein:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> - Cut
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> - Copy
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> - Paste